# error in running a jar using java code

Tags: java, swing, jar

I have a java swing application to extract text from pdf. It works fine when i run using command prompt(`java -jar xyz.jar`) or double click and run the jar but it gets stuck when I run using java code

```
Process asm = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar xyz.jar");
asm.waitFor();
```

or using process builder. is it because of the exceptions in my application? I'm not sure.

Comment: You probably need another thread to consume the program's output streams, otherwise this code dead-locks.

Comment: Can u make it clear, how to do that?

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Comment: great link...it worked fyn..thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You probably aren't in the proper directory.

Use the [directory()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory%28java.io.File%29) method of ProcessBuilder so that the external process is run in the correct place so that the jar can be found.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java -jar xyz.jar");
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
processBuilder.directory(  complete this );
Process process = processBuilder.start();
String output = readOutput(process);
try {
    if (process.waitFor() != 0) {
        throw new IOException("command exited in error: " + process.exitValue() + "\n" + output);
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, print the output streams (including the error one) to see what happens.

Comment: actually jar is running,but it is getting stuck in middle

Comment: I suppose you can print the state/exceptions on the console and read the console using processbuilder outputs ? What does that show ?