# Failing during creating jar by processbuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am creating jar file from class files by following command in cmd. working fine.

```
C:\>cd \GenClass
C:\>path c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_09\bin;%path%
C:\>echo Main-Class: myjar >manifest.txt
C:\>jar cvfm myjar.jar manifest.txt proxy/*.class
```

But the same thing I am failing in processbuilder.

```
    ProcessBuilder pb1= new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "jar cvfm contactproxy.jar manifest.txt proxy/*.class");
    pb1.directory(new File("D:\\GenClass"));
    pb1.environment().put("CLASSPATH", "D:\\java\\jdk1.5.0_14\\bin");

    java.lang.Process p1 = pb1.start();
    String line1;
    BufferedReader r1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));
    while ((line1 = r1.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line1);
    }
    r1.close();
```

jar could not be created.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: better print from p1.getErrorStream() to see what's going wrong.

Comment: error saying 'jar.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command. I guess I am failing to set the classpath properly.

Comment: PATH and CLASSPATH are different things. When using commandline, you set PATH, but when using process builder, you set CLASSPATH.

Comment: try looking from this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080224/error-in-running-a-jar-using-java-code

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov changed classpath to path. but no joy

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "jar.exe", write full path starting from c:\java.